# How to remove special characters along with <br>

Tags: c#, regex

Hi all i am having a string as follows

`string abc= "1) ABC <br> 2) SHJKL <br> 3) SJLKK JJJLHH";`

I tried this `Regex` but i didn't get as per required

`string str = Regex.Replace(abc, "[^a-zA-Z0-9% ._]", string.Empty);`

I need the output as `abcSHJKLSJLKKJJJLHH`

Comment: What is the output you get now?

Comment: `1 ABC br 2 SHJKL br 3 SJLKK JJJLHH`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following replaces anything that (is not an character or an open bracket) with string.empty:

```
string str = Regex.Replace(abc, "[^(a-z)]|[^(A-Z)]|[\\)]", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 3):

you just need to have the list of all strings to be replaced with an OR - "|" between them:

```
string str = Regex.Replace(abc, @"\d\)|[ ]|<br>", string.Empty);
```